# Can't close a QMenu opened through dbus by double clicking in another app

Tags: qt, dbus, qmenu

I have 2 applications, 1 has a QMenu that can be opened through DBus ("menu" app) and the other can open that menu by double clicking ("clicking" app).

When I open the menu by double clicking in the "clicking" app the menu doesn't close when I click outside of the menu.

The menu closes when:

- opened through qdbus in the terminal
- opened through single click in "clicking" app
- pressing Esc key

If the menu belongs to the same app then it closes.

## Here are the 2 applications

### https://gitlab.com/fbg/qmenu-dbus-test

Expected Result:

1. open both apps
2. double click "clicking" app
3. menu from "menu" app opens
4. click outside menu
5. menu closes

Actual Result:

1-4 same as above

5. menu doesn't close, unless I click in "menu" app's window or press the Esc key

### Edit:

Behaviour happens in Solus 4.0

- KDE Plasma Version: 5.15.3
- KDE Frameworks Version: 5.56.0
- Qt Version: 5.12.2

In lubuntu (lxqt) the menu shows for a split second and then closes.

A simpler way to test this is to use qdbusviewer.

1. build and run [testqmenudbus2](https://gitlab.com/fbg/qmenu-dbus-test)
2. open qdbusviewer
3. find the service org.TestQMenu
4. find the method showMenu in TestQMenu.local.MainWindow
5. double click method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Solved](https://gitlab.com/fbg/qmenu-dbus-test/commit/f9b580f71650857bfe452ec36fe8c9c7f7b1041a) it by adding

```
QThread::msleep(150);
```

to the dbus method before showing the menu.

Might be just a workaround though.